# Inverse covariance matrix for a Gaussian state

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-optics, quantum-computer, bosons

I was reading an article about Gaussian Boson Sampling (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1801.07488.pdf) and following some calculation appear an inverse covariance matrix when he defines the following matrix A.

$A=\left( \begin{array}{cc} 0 & I_n \\
I_n & 0 \end{array} \right)[I_{2n}-\sigma_Q^{-1}]$

where $\sigma_Q=\sigma-I_{2n}/2$  and $I_n$ is the identity matrix nxn.

The covariance matrix is defined as:

$\sigma_{ij}=\frac{1}{2} \langle \{\zeta_i \zeta_j^{\dagger}\} \rangle -d_id_j^{*}$,  $~d_i=\langle \zeta_i\rangle$

where $\zeta_i$ is a vector of length 2n that runs over all creation and annihilation operators and we assume $d_i=0$.

I made the calculation to know the form of $\sigma$ and found something like a block matrix:

$\sigma=\left( \begin{array}{cc} A & B \\
B^{*} & A^{*} \end{array} \right)$

Where the entries of each block are $A_{ij}=\frac{1}{2} \langle \{a_j,a_j^{\dagger}\} \rangle$ and $B_{ij}=\langle a_j a_j \rangle$ . $\sigma$ is a hermitian matrix.

So finally I want to know how to calculate $\sigma^{-1}$ to find A with some form like

$A=\left( \begin{array}{cc} B & C \\
C^{t} & B^{*} \end{array} \right)$

as in the article.

Some idea or insight is very welcome.

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v1): In the future please link to abstract pages rather than pdf files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For block matrices we have the Helmert–Wolf formula
$$
\left(\matrix{{\bf A}& {\bf B}\cr {\bf C}&{\bf D}}\right)^{-1}
=\left(\matrix{({\bf A}^{-1}+{\bf A}^{-1}{\bf B}({\bf D}-{\bf C} {\bf A}^{-1}{\bf B}) {\bf C}{\bf A}^{-1} & -{\bf A}^{-1}{\bf B}({\bf D}-{\bf C}{\bf A}^{-1}{\bf B})^{-1}
\cr -({\bf D}-{\bf C}{\bf A}^{-1}{\bf B})^{-1}{\bf C}{\bf A}^{-1} & ({\bf D}-{\bf C}{\bf A}^{-1}{\bf B})^{-1}}\right).
$$
Here ${\bf A}$ and ${\bf D}$ must be square but the other entries can be rectangular as long as they are multiplication compatible.

Comment: How could they not be multiplication compatible?

Comment: I@ Norbert Schuch: In a product ${\bf A B}$ the number of rows of ${\bf B}$ must equal the number of columns of ${\bf A}$ for the product  to be defined.

Comment: That's interesting!  But how can [A B;C D] be a matrix if this condition is not satisfied?

Comment: BTW, is "Helmert-Wolf formula" an established name for that?  For me, this was always the prime application of Schur complements.  Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix#Blockwise_inversion) lists different sources for the formula, but not Helmert or Wolf.

Comment: @ Norbert Schuch. I think it is mostly that they made extensive use of the formula that I have seen their names attached. Yes, it is probably due to Issai Schur.

Comment: @ Norbert Schuch.  You can have ${\bf A}$ and ${\bf D}$ being squares of differen sizes. Then ${\bf B}$ and ${\bf C}$ will be rectangular. I guess they always fit properly though, so you are right in that it is not an extra condition.

Comment: Indeed, they always fit properly, so it is not an extra condition.  That was precisely my point.